# Faint Grid Visible in Final Render

Tags: rendering, artifacts

I have a project using the dry lakebed procedural texture discussed in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJGphR_LBoM as pictured (only visible at full size):
[image]

This looks OK, but on close inspection I can see a faint grid, especially near the center horizon. It looks a little like the Blender world grid, but this was rendered with it turned off. There is only this single plane in the image. Using Blender 2.93.3.

What could be causing this? I've tried all sorts of things to get rid of it, to no avail.

Adding node tree per requests.

[image: node tree]

Comment: You appear to be using a repeating texture, and as the texture retreats into the background, it produces the effect.

Comment: @MartyFouts I would’ve said the same thing, but it says it’s a Procedural Texture. Anyway, can you add screenshots, Mr. Bacon?

Comment: Yeah, it's all procedural textures - Musgrave, Voronoi, and Noise. No images involved. Is the screenshot I posted not visible?

Comment: @TheLabCat you can tile procedural textures and some of them, like magic, or Voronoi when randomness is low, are self tiling anyway.

Comment: Do you have the scale set high or the randomness low on the Voronoi?  I think that's what's causing the effect.  The screenshot is visible, but I'd like to see one of the material node tree that's readable if I could.

Comment: Added node tree. I'm not sure what counts as high or low in such a case; apart from the Musgrave lacunarity they all seem pretty middling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real answer for this, but I did find a workaround. The scene above has the plane oriented at the origin, coincident with the x and y axes, with the camera looking almost straight up the bore of the y axis. If I rotate the view a bit, the grid shifts and disappears in the center of the view. If the view rotates enough so no part of the camera's angle of view can see along this axis, problem is "solved." Also tried fiddling with texture parameters quite a bit, but to no avail.

It's not a great workaround. There's obviously something not quite right about how Blender applies textures. But it's enough of a solution for my immediate needs as I won't be using a very wide angle camera.

The grid is not visible if I point the camera along the x axis in either direction. It is visible only along the +/- y axis. Or more properly along those directions on the material, which is already aligned with the world axes.

Comment: I think it might have to do with adaptive subdiv, being exactly on-axis. Check out the scene with a  _Wireframe_ (input node) to have a look at that.. does the effect disappear if you Z-rotate your plane a tiny bit?

Comment: Had the same thought, but a small rotation doesn't fix it; it just shifts the grid in the opposite direction of the rotation as noted. Is there a way to offset or rotate the subdiv?